# Identify AJAX errors

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, svg

I have a php file which has svg embedded in php variable. Using an onclick event on the svg elements displayed (lines with ID's) I want to change the colour of the SVG element and then send a parameter to a mysql table to return the x and y coords etc of other lines which join my selected line.

This part unto sending the parameter to mysql table works fine using ajax in my javascript function:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"      
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="application/json" />
<title>Enter Exercises</title>
</head>

<script type="text/javascript"
src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"> </script>
<script type="text/javascript">

function GetPathways(elt)
{
    document.getElementById(elt.id).style.stroke = "blue";
    var test=elt.id;
    var test = document.getElementById(elt.id);
    test.setAttribute("x2", "550");
     test.setAttribute("y2", "450");       
    document.getElementById(elt.id).style.visibility = "visible";
    var exid = parseInt(elt.id);

    $.ajax(
    {                                      
      type: "POST",
      url: 'GetPathways.php',                     
      data: {id: exid},                                                      
      dataType: 'json',                  
      contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',

        success: function(message)         
      {
        alert (message);
      },

        error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError)
        {
           alert("Error code is....:"+xhr.status);
        }
    });   
};
</script>
```

Ajax calls php file which executes the sql required to return the table rows (multiple). I have tested the query in my phpAdmin and it works fine retrieving some appropriate rows of data.

Ajax script however only executes error function and not the success function.

The success function will eventually use the ID of the returned svg element to be displayed ie update the webpage based on the onclick event. Seems like a good use of ajax to refresh page  without reloading.

GetPathways.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="application/json" />
<title>Get Pathways</title>
</head>

<body>
<?php

//echo "Hello from processing file GetPathways.php"."<br>";
header("Content-Type: application/json");
$dbname = 'TTexercises';
$dbuser = 'dummy entry';
$dbpass = 'dummy entry';
$dbhost = 'localhost:3036';


# set the database connection to be used using php function
$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass) or die("Unable to   
Connect to '$dbhost'");

# select the database to be used using php function

mysql_select_db($dbname) or die("Could not open the db '$dbname'");


$id = $_POST['id'];

$query = "SELECT * FROM `PathwayTable` WHERE `EndPathwayID`= $id";

mysql_query($query);


mysql_close($conn);
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Error code is 200

Comment: what is the error you are getting in xhr.status and also post GetPathways.php code

Comment: Your data and your contentType do not match.

Comment: Assuming you are using a competent browser then press F12, go to the network tab, reload your page, initiate the AJAX call, find the AJAX call in the network tab and click/double-click it to see details.

Comment: I am assuming that the mysql return would be an array - so what data and content type is required - cant find confirmation of this in any of the ajax tutorials I have seen.

Answer (score 0):

You have to echo the data inorder to get response from ajax call and also you did not execute the query. change the GetPathways.php  as follows

```
<?
header("Content-Type: application/json");
$dbname = 'TTexercises';
$dbuser = 'dummy entry';
$dbpass = 'dummy entry';
$dbhost = 'localhost:3036';


# set the database connection to be used using php function
$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass) or die("Unable to   
Connect to '$dbhost'");

# select the database to be used using php function

mysql_select_db($dbname) or die("Could not open the db '$dbname'");


$id = $_POST['id'];

$query = "SELECT * FROM `PathwayTable` WHERE `EndPathwayID`= $id LIMIT 1";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$value = mysql_fetch_object($result);
mysql_close($conn);
print_r($value);

?>
```